# recharts customize issue - how to adjust the chart values position

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I customize PieChartWithCustomizedLabel in recharts by adding outerRadius, but the problem it cause is values inside charts overlap their area(not properly in side the relevant area) and I can't adjust the position of the values inside this chart. How can we adjust the position of the values inside this chart?

[Here is the picture of the chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93g7i.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you can change your 'value' position by changing 'radius' const in PieChartWithCustomizedLabel in Recharts

```
const radius = innerRadius + (outerRadius - innerRadius) * 0.5;
```

In the first time it was difficult to me too, to find how to adjust the 'value' position